# Lombok in enum : @Setter is giving compile error in enum

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

Error : @Setter is only supported on a class or a field.
lombok version in pom.xml = 1.18.12

want to make this ErrorMessages generic for any type of error.
Need to create getter and setter through lombok and access like : ErrorMessages.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD.getErrorMessage()

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
public enum ErrorMessages {

    MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD("Missing required field. Please check documentation for required fields."),
    RECORD_ALREADY_EXISTS("Record already exists");

    private String errorMessage;

//  public String getErrorMessage() {
//      return errorMessage;
//  }
//
//  public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
//      this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
//  }

    ErrorMessages(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;

    }

}
```

Comment: `enum` are supposed to be immutable. Having a setter on them runs counter to the very idea.

Answer (score 1):

this should be a `class` , not an `enum`, if you wan't the data to be changed otherwise see  Joachim Sauer comment.

Also please note the constructor need to be public as well

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class ErrorMessages {

    private String errorMessage;

    public ErrorMessages(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;}
}
```

Comment: Er, better yet, `@Value public class....`. Naming a class ErrorMessages (plural) is odd as well, but it's hard to fathom what the question asker is attempting to do with this code.

Comment: I agree that @Data can be used here as well

Comment: want to make this ErrorMessages generic for any type of error. Need to create getter and setter through lombok and access like : ErrorMessages.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD.getErrorMessage()

Using @Data giving same error - supported on a class